# Excel index formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've got a bit of an issue in Excel. A document I exported has a thousand or so rows and about 80 columns. The columns all refer to a certain attribute of the data, and I want to collate it all in to a single column with the text being the column name. What formula can I use to do this? I've tried to lay out an example below.

Attribute___A__B__C__D

XLM_1__A_1
XLM_2__C_______         1
XLM_3__B____        1
XLM_4__ D__________             1

Comment: This is rather difficult to follow. Can you please explain clearer? Giving an example of what the data looks like now and what you are trying to achieve would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to make a little table, but the formatting messed up. Looking at my table, there are five columns, the name of a trade, the "attribute" of the trade, and then the four attributes, A,B,C,&D. Whether a trade has that attribute or not is denoted by a 1 in the appropriate column.
I'm wondering how I can generate the "attribute" column that summarises the data in the A,B,C&D columns.

Comment: It is still not making sense to me. Your table looks like a mix of your data now and what you want it to be. I think the underscores are throwing me off visually. Is the attribute `XML_1` or is that `XML`, then `1` in column A? Rather than try to build a text table, can you give us a screenshot of  your spreadsheet now and then an example of what you want it to look like? Or maybe use [something like this](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) to help you format it correctly in text.